# How to activate the example watchface in Android Studio

Tags: wear-os

- I have configured and successfully built the example wearOS watchface
  example in Android Studio.
- I built it and signed it. I used ADB to connect to and install the watchface .APK to the watch.
- ADB says it was successfully installed. And in fact, using the ADB shell command I invoked the package manager and it is showing up as an installed package (but in the package:/data/app/ area ???)
- I'm stuck.   I can't find a way to activate it and make it the default watchface.
- Can somebody give me a hint how to make it available and activate it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you enabled developer mode on the watch?

Comment: Yes...   Developer mode is turned on as well as the ability for ADB to connect and do things to the watch.     The problem is, when I try to change the watch face to the example one, it isn't in the list of available watch faces.

Comment: I haven't gone through the example tutorial, but I did clone the repository and was able to get the completed version that they provided to run. Are you able to get that to run properly? This will help to determine the source of the issue.

Comment: What I did was start Android Studio.    I then did:
- Import an Android code sample
- Selected Wearable / Watch Face

That got all the code and associated files into Android Studio.   I built and signed it successfully.    I connected to the watch with ADB and installed it successfully.

The big problem is, I can find a way to 'activate' it and make it display.  There are plenty of different watch faces to choose from.   But the example one isn't available.

Comment: did you do this example? could you help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382574/how-to-run-watchface-for-wearos-codelab

Answer (score 0):

Long-press on the current watchface until it shrinks.

Swipe left until you reach the last item with "+ See more watch faces".
Tap on it.

Swipe up and look carefully. If your watchface installed in the right place, it will be there. Tap on it. Now it is selected as your current watchface and will appear in the favorite list.

No? Then you may try and install it directly from Android Studio. It works for me every time. No signing required.