# How to run "Watchface for wearos" codelab?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android and WearOS and also to Gradle, and I just want to follow along this Codelab:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/watchface/index.html#0

So I downloaded Android Studio and imported the project

https://github.com/googlecodelabs/watchface

but when compiling I just get the error

Failed to resolve: com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0

I already tried to change SDK Versions and other things, but it didn't help.
I'm pretty sure it's just a few version settings, but I have no idea where to look.

Did anyone maybe complete this codelab and made it run with the "actual" version of AndroidStudio?

thanks,
Thorsten

Comment: This project seems more up to date than the codelab: https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/master/WatchFace

Answer (score 0):

The code on github was last updated in May 2017, which is a shame, as it is a useful introduction to watchfaces. A number of things have changed since then. There is even a pull request on github with gradle updates from Nov 2018, but it hasn't been merged.

Your 'Failed to resolve' error is likely related to Google now providing some packages in their own Maven repository, in addition to jcenter.

This can be fixed by adding google() to the repositories closures in the Package build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

The version of the gradle plugin has been changed to 4.0.2 above too, so also update the file gradle-wrapper.properties with:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

Gradle should now build, but it may still log some warnings or errors in the Build window which you can open at the bottom of Android Studio.

The gradle dependency keyword 'provided' has been replaced with 'compileOnly' and 'compile' with 'implementation'. Shift+Ctrl+R in Android Studio will enable you to easily do the replacement project-wide.

It should also be useful for updating compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion (to 30) and buildToolsVersion (to 30.0.2) in all the module build.gradle files.

The package versions are out of date, with the wearable ones currently at 2.8.1 and play-services-wearable at 17.0.0. Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S takes you to 'Suggestions' in 'Project Structure', which can help you in future to stay current.

The last problem is that the Android Support Library has been obsoleted in favor of jetpack/androidx. See the [old reference](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages).

In this project, it is only a problem in the build.gradle of module 5-palette. You may replace 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.3.0' with 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'. See [Jetpack Artifact Mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings). You then need to change the import statement in MyWatchFaceService.java.

Finally add the following line to gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```